# How to delete firebase email authentication users in python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication, gae-python27

Currently I have email authenticated users on my firebase account using the new authentication api. Currently I am not using the real time database to store my users I am using the default email and password to authentication store user information. There is no admin sdk for python that allows me to delete users in firebase that aren't in the real time database. My question is how to delete the users that appear in only the authentication part of firebase using the libraries in python so I can manage users on the server side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User Management outside of the console now supports python, go, and java. 
How to delete a user with python:

```
from firebase_admin import auth
auth.delete_user(uid)
```

> Here's the API:
>
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user